# JSF - List of supported Browsers

Tags: cross-browser, jsf-2

Can someone help me to find out the list of all Supported Browsers for JSF2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically the JSF is converted to html on the server side like JSP and php and such, so unless you are doing something really crazy or using a feature not supported by certain browsers yet (CSS3 or HTML5) it should work with most browsers

(source: I've used my JSF apps on IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera Mobile with no issues so far)

I wasn't able to find a place online that officially lists supprted browsers, only sites like IceFaces and RichFaces

just found this, not actually looking for it but thought it might be useful
[CaniUse.com](http://caniuse.com/) lets you select features and then it shows a table of browsers and whether they support the features or not

Comment: Yeah, but in fact maybe there are some issues if you use some advanced component, such as `f:ajax` ? I really don't know, that's why I ask this :)

Comment: well ajax is just a mix of javascript and html right so if the browser doesn't support javascript I would say it doesn't support that tag...right? but I think most browsers support javascript

Comment: [W3C Schools AJAX Intro](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp)
says that ajax is browser and platform independent so you should be good to go :) but @BalusC is much more familiar with JSF so he might be able to correct me if I am wrong